# Firefox - Focus menu on alt+tab

Tags: windows-7, firefox, alt-tab

I'm having a strange issue with firefox 25.0.1 on my desktop computer. Whenever I alt+tab **to** firefox, it automatically displays top menu bar and highlights "file". As a result of this, the focus from main window is removed and I've to focus the main window back using my mouse. This is getting very annoying for me.

This issue is not present on my laptop firefox 25.0.1 so it is installation specific. I might have played with settings in `about:blank` in past so if it might be related to that. 
I'm running windows 7 and using a apple keyboard+mouse, if that matters.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is happening only with Firefox, can you please check this in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)? If it's okay, you can then delete the new profile, and [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) from the other (old) profile which ensures the automatic migration of personal data.

Comment: I've created a new profile. It didn't happen in new profile for some alt+tabs but has started happening eventually. I'm suspecting the keyboard?

Comment: If you can check with another keyboard then it could probably be a definite way to isolate the problem.

Comment: Does the issue still exist with the current version? I have to work with 27 showing the same issue and wonder if upgrading would fix it.

Comment: I'm using 32.0.2 and can't reproduce the issue. In fact it disappeared quite a while ago, which I think must have been because of firefox auto-updating.

Comment: In case your menu bar is hidden by default, it may help to always show it. This solves the issue of the `File` menu opening, but the menu bar is still focussed.